# c++ how do you implement a has relationship?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

for example:
i got great reservations:
the class has memeber the start/end date and a function that gives me the date.

```
class reservation{
    private:
    datetime start;
    datetime end;

    public:
    reservation(stardatetime, enddatetime): start(stardatetime), end(enddatetime)
      {

      }

    std::list<std::string> get_reservation()
      {
        for example: return start; 
        }
    };
```

and i have a class conference room, which can be booked from one time to another.

```
  class room{
        private: 
        int room_ID;
        public:
        room(int id):room_ID(id)
          {
          }
       void get_room(){
           return room_id;
           }
        }
```

that means every room has several reservations. 
how can i access through a room id via the reservation? 
if i search for room **id 1**, the reservation of the room will also be displayed.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe add a `int room_id;` field to `reservation` class?

Comment: can you please explain more to me, I am still a beginner and would be happy to receive more information. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem statement: every room has many reservations, and every reservation has a reference to a single room. Based on this, I would write it as follows (you may add your stuff inside those classes).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Room; //forward declaration

class Reservation {
private:
    Room* room;
public:
    Reservation(Room* roomPtr) {
        room = roomPtr;
    }
};

class Room {
    vector<Reservation> reservations;
};


int main(){

    Room room[10];  //an array of 10 rooms with no reservations (calls def.constructor of each Room)
    Reservation r1(&room[0]);   //reservation object r1 reserving room[0]
    Reservation r2(&room[1]);   //reservation object r2 reserving room[1]
//  ...more stuff goes here

}
```

Comment: I still don't understand. How does the program know which reservation belongs to which room?
Sorry, I'm still a beginner. What am I supposed to do with room in reservations class?

Comment: For any particular reservation you just need to call a specific public function (not included in my example above) which would return a copy of its pointer pointing to the Room object that it has reserved. I.e. ```Room* getRoom() {return room;}```